# 1px Line When Placing/Pasting Illustrator Shape in to Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

We recently created a new logo and every time we paste/place the logo in Photoshop, we get a strange 1px line between two shapes in the logo, going vertically through the middle.

So here's the 612px x 612px Illustrator Export
[image: So here's the 612px x 612px Illustrator Export]

And here's the exact same shape copied, and pasted into a 612px x 612px Photoshop document.
[image: And here's the exact same shape copied, and pasted into a 612px x 612px Photoshop document.]

Notice the 1px line down the middle?

Here's some info that might be relevant:

- Each segment is white with a % transparency.
- Each segment is aligned exactly point-to-point with 'Align to Pixel grid' turned off in the
  illustrator document.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are your objects grouped when you copy and paste them? I've been able to replicate the behaviour you've found. For some strange reason, I've found copying groups brings in that single pixel line.

Grouped:

[image]

Ungrouped:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely because the objects are grouped! Thanks!